# What is begin() == end()?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

[array.zero-2](http://eel.is/c++draft/array#array.zero-2) says:

> In the case that `N == 0`, `begin() == end()` == unique value. The
>   return value of `data()` is unspecified.

What does this unique value mean? Does it mean that the result of the expression `begin() == end()` is a unique value? I don't see how that makes any sense, as a bool can only be true or false, which isn't very unique. I ran the following tests:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 0> test;
    auto b = test.begin();
    auto e = test.end();
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
              << (test.begin() == test.end())
              << std::is_same<bool, decltype(test.begin() == test.end())>::value
              << std::is_same<bool, decltype(b == e)>::value;
}
```

It all outputs `true` as expected. Then I wondered maybe it would be different for a non zero-sized array:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 0> test;
    std::array<int, 1> test2;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_same<
                    decltype(test.begin() == test.end()),
                    decltype(test2.begin() == test2.end())
                >::value
              << std::is_same<
                    decltype(test.begin()),
                    decltype(test2.begin())
                >::value;
}
```

Again all true. So what does "unique value" mean? What has a unique value?

Answer (score 6):

`begin() == end() == unique value` is more of a logical description than actual C++. It's stating that begin() is the same as end(), and both of them are equal to some unique value.

Basically is the logical expression 'a=b=c', except using the C++ `==`.

Answer (score 3):

`begin()==end()==unique value` is standard-eze shorthand, rather than a C++ expression.

It just means that `begin()` and `end()` can be evaluated without causing undefined behaviour, and they can be compared for equality.  To do that for a zero-element array, they need to give a valid (comparable) value, even if that value cannot be dereferenced (used to access an array element or any variable of that type - which is the case for `end()`).

It probably would have been easier if they said that with more words, but that's life.  Lots of people shoot for brevity over ease of understanding.   Whoever wrote it probably thinks like a mathematician, but felt they had to use C++ syntax.